# Django URLs.py - url not recognized and registered namespaces

Tags: django, url, namespaces, registration

My issue is with a template where i build in a url tag. This is the template part which causes the error:

```
39                      <div class="table-data__tool-right">
40                          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" href="{% url 'doctormonthbilling_export:add' %}/{{ month }}/{{ doctorid }}">
41                              <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>
42                              Rechnung erstellen
43                          </button>
44                      </div>
```

and this is the error:

```
'doctormonthbilling_export' is not a registered namespace

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/doctormonthbilling/3/2
Django Version:     3.0.8
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    


'doctormonthbilling_export' is not a registered namespace

Exception Location:     C:\mySF\mySF\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py in reverse, line 83
Python Executable:  C:\mySF\mySF\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.4
Python Path:    

['C:\\mySF\\mySF',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\mySF\\mySF\\venv',
 'C:\\mySF\\mySF\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

even though i have the line in my urls.py file like the following:

```
# some paths before with ,    
path('doctormonthbilling_export/<str:month>/<str:doctorid>', views.doctormonthbilling_export,name='doctormonthbilling_export'),
#some other paths after
```

i can't figure out what's wrong! Can anyone spot the error? Thanks

Comment: check if your app urls is registered on on main urls (the one with settings) can you please show your urls cofiguration? views and template will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove ":add" from `{% url 'doctormonthbilling_export:add' %}`?

Comment: Add trailing slash at the end of url `path('doctormonthbilling_export/<str:month>/<str:doctorid>/'`

Comment: well i kinda need that since you know my path looks like 'doctormonthbilling_export/<str:month>/<str:doctorid>' and i need to add the month parameter and the doctorid parameter ...

Comment: @ItsMilann i will try that

Comment: @ItsMilann it doesn't change a thing, if i remove the :add, i get a parameter error....

Answer (score 0):

well apparently the following works:
i changed this line:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" href="{% url 'doctormonthbilling_export:add' %}/{{ month }}/{{ doctorid }}">
```

to this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" onclick="location.href='{% url 'doctormonthbillingexport' month='{{ month }}' doctorid='{{ doctorid }}'  %}'">
```

and changed the name from doctormonthbilling_export to doctormonthbillingexport. ‍♂️ and now it works for whatever reason.